# How to float center but move right if needed?

Tags: html, css, css-float

I would like to display three columns in a row.

- The first one is at far left
- The second one in the center
- The third one is at far right

When the content of the first column is very long, I would like to second column to move to the right.

Here is my CSS code

```
.col {
    display: block;
    float: left;
}

.column1 {
   width: 45%;
   vertical-align: middle;
   padding-left: 10px;
   padding-top: 3px;
}

.column2 {
   text-align: left;
   vertical-align: middle;
   padding-top: 3px;
   /* 55% - padding left - col3 - padding-right */
   width: -moz-calc(55% - 50px);
   width: -webkit-calc(55% - 50px);
   width: calc(55% - 50px);
}
```

And HTML

```
<div class="col column1">
   Here is some short text
</div>

<div class="col column2">
   Text to be centered
</div>

<div class="col column3">
   XXX
</div>
```

You can view the result here: https://codepen.io/Jibeji/pen/qoBqjR

Comment: `div`s are display block by default, no need to define it

Answer (score 0):

I kept your HTML as it was and altered your CSS. Is this what you are looking for?

```
.col {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}

.column1 {
   min-width: 45%;
   vertical-align: middle;
   padding-left: 10px;
   padding-top: 3px;
}

.column2 {
   text-align: left;
   vertical-align: middle;
   padding-top: 3px;
   /* 55% - padding left - dpt - padding-right */
   max-width: -moz-calc(55% - 50px);
   max-width: -webkit-calc(55% - 50px);
   max-width: calc(55% - 50px);
}

.column3 {
  float: right;
}
```

Comment: No I'd like to have column1 "pushing" slightly column2 to the right when column1 is very long.

Answer (score 0):

As easy as that:

```
.col {
    float: left;
}

.column1 {
   min-width: 45%;
   vertical-align: middle;
   padding-left: 10px;
   padding-top: 3px;
}

.column2 {
   text-align: left;
   vertical-align: middle;
   padding-top: 3px;
}

.column3 {
  float: right;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Flexbox can do that.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 1em auto;
}

.col {
  flex: 1;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  padding: 5px;
}

.column1 {
  text-align: left
}

.column3 {
  text-align: right
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="col column1">
    Here is some short text
  </div>

  <div class="col column2">
    Text to be centered
  </div>

  <div class="col column3">
    XXX
  </div>

</div>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="col column1">
    Here is some loooooooooooongtext
  </div>
  <div class="col column2">
    Text to be centered
  </div>

  <div class="col column3">
    XXX
  </div>
</div>
```